# Constructing continuous Functions based on Unbounded Sets.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

The question asks the following:

"For each of the sets, construct a continuous function that is unbounded on the set.",

However, I am completely lost on what I should do or even begin. Some of the sets include:

- $(2,3)$
- $\mathbb{N}$ (The Natural Numbers)

These aren't all the sets, but if I can see how the problem could be approached it would be appreciated.

Comment: I give you an example for $(2,3)$. Consider the function $f(x)=1/(x-2)$. This function is continuous in $\mathbb R\backslash\{2\}$ and hence in your set, but it is unbounded...

Comment: Hmm okay I see where you're going with it. How could it wouldn't be f(x) = 1/(x-2)(x-3)?

Comment: That would work well ;)

Comment: The function must be continuous on the set or in $\mathbb{R}$?